# WSGI permission error when deploying flask app to apache2

Tags: linux, flask, apache2

```
[Mon Jan 24 17:01:59.755348 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 6837:tid 139969656289024] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] mod_wsgi (pid=6837): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/FlaskDeliverN/app.wsgi'.
[Mon Jan 24 17:01:59.755407 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 6837:tid 139969656289024] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] mod_wsgi (pid=6837): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskDeliverN/app.wsgi'.
[Mon Jan 24 17:01:59.760074 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 6837:tid 139969656289024] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jan 24 17:01:59.760109 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 6837:tid 139969656289024] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx]   File "/var/www/FlaskDeliverN/app.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[Mon Jan 24 17:01:59.760114 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 6837:tid 139969656289024] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx]     with open(activate_this) as file_:
[Mon Jan 24 17:01:59.760129 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 6837:tid 139969656289024] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskDeliverN-8O9_IGcY/bin/activate_this.py'
```

I keep on getting the above error. I am not sure why there would be a permission error here. I checked that the file existed and wasn't empty so that's not the issue. I have looked through many tutorials on how to deploy a flask app but it never works and I think this may be why.

I followed this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0QDAg85Oow

Comment: Probably because your virtualenv is in the `/root/` directory. Don't put anything there. Recreate the virtualenv somewhere else as a normal user, so the apache `www-user` can read the files.